# Dynamically replace form with message upon submission

Tags: php, html, forms

I've written a basic PHP script to generate an email when my contact form is submitted, but as it stands, it redirects the user to an error or thankyou page, which is a little clunky. I'd love to dynamically replace the entire form (or, at least, the submit button) with an error or success message. The problem here is that my PHP knowledge is limited.

**HTML:**

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="contact-form.php">
    <input type="text" class="input-field" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required data-errormessage-value-missing="Hey, I need your name!" />
    <input type="email" class="input-field" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required data-errormessage-value-missing="Don't forget your email address!" />
    <textarea name="message" class="textarea-field" id="message" placeholder="Message" required data-errormessage-value-missing="Please enter your message."></textarea>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeJpAsTAAAAALzJoRZzq4_fovbjjSG2iaxvVHzy"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Contact Me" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl" />             
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

// Load reCAPTCHA library
include_once ("autoload.php");

$name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']));
$email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
$message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['message']));
$emailFrom = $email;
$emailTo = "my@email.com";
$subject = "Contact Request";

// Prepare email body text
$body = "<strong>Name:</strong> $name <br /> <strong>Email:</strong> $email <br /> <strong>Message:</strong> $message";

$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $name <$emailFrom>" . "\r\n";

$secret = 'XXX';
$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret);
$resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'],$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if ($resp->isSuccess()){
    $success = mail($emailTo,$subject,$body,$headers);
    header("Location: " . "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/thankyou.html');
}else{
    header("Location: " . "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/error.html');
}

?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is where AJAX comes in handy...

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    echo 'Your message goes here.';
}
else
{
?>

    <!-- Your form HTML goes here. -->

<?php
}
```

EDIT:  Sorry, I didn't look closely enough at your html.  Try the following.  Put all the existing PHP code you have into a contact-form.php file.  Put the html form you have in index.php.  In the PHP code, remove the `header` statements and replace them with `echo` statements - whatever message you want to put there.

Comment: How does this mix with the last `if` statement in my script that redirects the user?

Comment: You can remove that if/else statement.  You can put error/success logic in the part where 'Your message goes here.'.

Comment: I thought so. I'm just trying to figure out the syntax. Do I add the code that you wrote in my index.html (which I'd have to turn into index.php?), or within my existing script? Thanks.

Comment: All of your existing PHP code and HTML form would go inside the `else` in my code (minus your if/else redirect statement).  You should only have index.php, not index.html.

Comment: I think I'm struggling with the syntax. Something like this? http://ideone.com/rFcudL.

Comment: All of the existing (my) PHP is already in contact-form.php and I renamed my index.html to index.php, but when I submit the form, I get a blank page. I've tried using echo before, but it displayed the messages on a new, white page. Does this change by using index.php instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87728/discussion-between-raduation-and-mario-parra).